# Is convergence of vectors equivalent to convergence of inner products

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Consider a net $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ and $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is the following true?

$$x_\alpha\rightarrow x ~\iff~ \langle x_\alpha,y\rangle\rightarrow\langle x,y\rangle,~\forall y\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$

I can prove ($\Rightarrow$) but get stuck on ($\Leftarrow$). (Convergence on the left is meant as in euclidean norm.)

Comment: All norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent . The convergence of $x_\alpha\to x$ is equivalent to $x_\alpha(k)\to x(k)$ for any $1\le k\le n.$

Answer (score 5):

Hint: let $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ a orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$

$$x_\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^n \left\langle x_\alpha, e_i\right\rangle e_i$$

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. (Was looking for more of a yes/no answer, just needed this thing to conclude the proof that one can identify a vector space of finite signed measures on a finite space with finite dimensional euclidean space so that the weak topology on measures coincides with the euclidean topology; I was sure I've seen this equivalence before but couldn't find it written out.)